# Trying to mount USB-drive automatically through udev; script complains that it's not superuser

Tags: linux, permissions, root, udev, privileges

I am trying to mount my USB-drive automatically on Linux. 
I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
mount /dev/safety1 /mnt/hd 2> /home/harald/errors/e
rsync -az /mnt/hd/ /home/harald/backups/ && umount /dev/safety1  2>> /home/harald/errors/e
```

After insertion of the USB stick,
the script gets called by the following `.rules`-code
that is saved in `/etc/udev/rules.d` (serial nr. is not really XXXXXX):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6387", ATTRS{idVendor}=="058f", ATTRS{product}=="USB DISK 3.1", ATTRS{serial}=="XXXXXX", ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="safety%n"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6387", ATTRS{idVendor}=="058f", ATTRS{product}=="USB DISK 3.1", ATTRS{serial}=="XXXXXX", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/trigger.sh"
```

The `.rules`-code is able to detect the insertion of the USB stick
and the bash script is being executed. 
However, I get the following error messages when running the code:

```
mount: /mnt/hd: permission denied.
umount: /dev/safety1: must be superuser to unmount.
```

I changed the permissions of `/mnt/hd` to `drwxr-xrwx`;
however, this did not solve the problem. 
Does anyone know how to solve this? 
How can I mount my device automatically through a script?

Comment: You should be able to just add the option `user` or  `users` to the corresponding line in `/etc/fstab` ...

Comment: Hi tink, to what line need user/users to be added in fstab? I added it under options to the line with the filesystem, on which /mnt/hd is placed (which is /dev/nvme0n1p6). This resulted in a crash of the system (which could be recovered). Did I understand you correctly?